# How to achieve specific layout in Xamarin.Forms for android / ios

Tags: c#, android, ios, user-interface, xamarin.forms

I would like to add multiple labels to the page and have them placed one after another. When they reach the end of the screen i want them to move to the next line and so forth.

Here is an example of what I am looking to do from the Next Door android app. Notice the stacking categories in blue.

What layout should be used and options / or method? I tried stacklayout but it doesnt work like that.

[image: example of stacking buttons and labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLabs has a [WrapLayout](http://xlabs.github.io/html/class_x_labs_1_1_forms_1_1_controls_1_1_wrap_layout.html) class that should do what you want.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, and so easy to implement. Thank you!